# Symbol not found - flutter iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I create the flutter project and run on vs code give me this error

Error launching application on Brainoid’s iPhone.

When this flutter project run on xcode, I get this errors

```
dyld[23669]: Symbol not found: _kReachabilityChangedNotification
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DBFB9E3-AA76-4519-9EBE-4C0A018FDA4A/Runner.app/Frameworks/connectivity.framework/connectivity
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DBFB9E3-AA76-4519-9EBE-4C0A018FDA4A/Runner.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
Symbol not found: _kReachabilityChangedNotification
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DBFB9E3-AA76-4519-9EBE-4C0A018FDA4A/Runner.app/Frameworks/connectivity.framework/connectivity
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DBFB9E3-AA76-4519-9EBE-4C0A018FDA4A/Runner.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
```

Comment: Which version of connectivity package are you using? Please include info.plist too

Comment: connectivity: ^3.0.6
  connectivity_plus: ^2.3.4

Comment: I'm getting same error for another SDK, Did you resolved this issue? If yes then please update your question with answer so other get help from it.